# Why Telerik RadGridView Header Show only Capitalized Font, how to change it to default? It happen in Office2013Theme

Tags: wpf

Why RadGridView Header Show only Capitalized Font, how to change it to default?
The RadGridView Header text is always Capital in this.I want to change it to default caption. It only happen in telerik Office2013 Theme. Can we solve using converter etc.?

this is my xaml code....

```
  <Grid>
        <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="MyGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                             VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ShowGroupPanel="False" 
                             AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        </telerik:RadGridView>
    </Grid>
```

this is c# code....

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;

            for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
            {
                UserData.Add("name"+i);
            }
            for (int i = 5; i < 9; i++)
            {
                UserData.Add("NAME" + i);
            }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<string> _userData=new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public ObservableCollection<string> UserData
        {
            get { return _userData; }
            set { _userData = value; }
        }
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var userName in UserData)
            {
                MyGrid.Columns.Add(new GridViewDataColumn
                {
                    Header = userName
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use inbuilt header use a template and go merry with it

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
            <TextBlock x:Name="HeaderTextBox"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      Margin="5"/>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>


HeaderTextBox.Text = "Merry Christmas";
```

Comment: I got the solution in **telerik** site. [telerik link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/office-2013-theme---how-to-not-uppercase-header-captions)